# Given some AABBs, find minimum total surface area AABBs that contain them all?

Tags: html, algorithm, math, graphics, html5-canvas

I have a number of objects that need to be rendered onto `HTML5` canvases. My input is an ordered list of axis-aligned bounding boxes. These boxes often overlap, but also often leave large areas of empty space between them.

I'd like to minimize the amount of canvas surface area I have to create to render all these items in the correct order, while not ever having to render parts of a single object on multiple canvases (thus preventing the easy solution of just creating canvases that tightly fit all of the occupied space).

So basically, I want tight groups of objects to all be rendered on the same canvas, while non-overlapping objects should be rendered on a separate canvas. But not all overlapping objects should be rendered on single canvases--for example, a very tall and very wide object that overlap slightly to form an L should still be rendered on two separate canvases, since combining them results in a lot of wasted canvas space in the open part of the L.

Maintaining Z order also results in some difficult cases. For example, the following image represents one potential arrangement:

[image]

In this case, you might want to combine the blue and green layers into a single canvas, but you can't produce correct layering that way without also including the red layer, and you'll end up with a lot of dead space.

But you also can't just limit combining layers to items that are consecutive in the Z order. The Z order might be the same as the above image, but the red item could happen to NOT overlap with the others, and in that case you DO want to combine the blue and green layers.

I'm struggling to come up with a good algorithm for this problem. Anyone care to chime in?

Comment: Just out of curiosity; why do you want to do this? The way you talk about "wasted canvas space" make it sound like a single large canvas with lots of empty space would be bad for performance or something. But wouldn't loads of smaller canvas elements give much worse performance, and be a major hassle to handle? Especially since you will have to position these canvases in relation to each other?
So, seeing all these problems, I wonder if there can really be a benefit big enough to outweigh them?

Comment: The problem is memory constraints on tablet browsers. Canvases are generally stored uncompressed, and on Chrome/Android always use 200% of their uncompressed size, rounded up to the next bigger tile size, in GPU memory, with no way to get them out of GPU memory other than destroying them.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is well known in 3D for building high-performance AABB hierarchies in ray-tracing or collision detection. Try to google for "BVH", "surface area heuristic" and/or "SAH".
Section 3.1 of the following paper has a good heuristic algorithm; which should be easy to adapt to your 2D case: http://graphics.stanford.edu/~boulos/papers/togbvh.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple suggestion, which probably doesn't address some corner cases, but would at least partially solve it, and hopefully suggest a better solution:

```
a = <a z-ordered list of the objects> ;
b = [];
bounds = null;
objects = [];
while ( a.length > 0) {
    c = a.pop();
    if( <c overlaps bounds> && <area of combined canvases> < <area of seperate canvases> || bounds === null) {
         objects.push(c);
         bounds = <union of bounds and c, or bounds of c if bounds is null>;
     } else {
          b.push(c);
     }
     if( a.length === 0) {
          a = b;
          b = [];
          <do something with the current bounds and objects list>
          bounds = null;
          objects = [];
     }
}
```

Where

```
 < area of combined canvases> = sum( < area of each canvas> ) - sum( <interesections> )
 < area of seperate conavases> = sum( < area of each canvas> )
```

This will not catch cases where you have two non-intersecting objects who both intersect a common object, but could probably be improved to do so by look back through all lower z-order objects at each iteration.

Comment: Although I haven't done a rigorous analysis, I believe a perfect solution for this problem will be NP. So, you should probably look for a solution that is "good enough."

Answer (score 0):

Starting with a z-ordered array of AABBs,

1. Add each AABB to a result array, also z-ordered

   a. Compare each of these to-be-added AABBs to all other AABBs already in the result array

   - See which combination of the to-be-added AABB and any other AABB would result in the smallest additional surface area. (It is possible that none will and the to-be-added AABB should not be combined with any others.)
   - When a combination would result in a smaller surface area, check for intersection issues (i.e. another AABB that overlaps the other AABB and is overlapped by the to-be-added AABB)
   - If no such intersection issues exist, remember this other AABB and continue looking for even better possible combinations

   b. When a best combination (or no combination) is finally found, add the to-be-added AABB to the result array

   - Depending on the presence of intersection issues, the to-be-added AABB may be combined with and inserted in the place of the other AABB in the result array
   - Otherwise, the combination or the new AABB by itself is added to the top of the result array
2. Repeat with the next AABB

It's not a pretty algorithm, nor does it do everything perfectly. For one thing, when a combination of AABBs is found, it does not try to find out whether a third or fourth (or fifth) AABB could also be added to the mix for improved area conservation.

Here's an implementation of this algorithm in Javascript:

```
algorithm = function(allAABBsInSortedOrder) {
    var smallestCanvasSurfaceArea = [];

    goog.array.forEach(allAABBsInSortedOrder, function(aabb) {
        smallestCanvasSurfaceArea = findSmallestSurfaceArea(aabb, smallestCanvasSurfaceArea);
    })
};

findSmallestSurfaceArea = function(nextAABB, combinedAABBsInSortedOrder) {
    var nextAABBarea = areaOf(nextAABB);

    if (!nextAABB) {
        return combinedAABBsInSortedOrder;
    }

    var aabbToCombineWith = {'index': -1, 'area': nextAABBarea, 'upOrDown': 0};

    goog.array.forEach(combinedAABBsInSortedOrder, function(aabb, idx) {
        // Improvement - exhaustive combinations (three AABBs? Four?)
        if (areaOf(combine(aabb, nextAABB) - nextAABBarea <= aabbToCombineWith['area']) {
            var overlapLower = false;
            var overlapNext = false;

            goog.array.forEach(combinedAABBsInSortedOrder, function(intersectAABB, intersectIdx) {
                if (intersectIdx > idx) {
                    if (checkForIntersect(aabb, intersectAABB)) {
                        overlapLower = true;
                    }
                    if (checkForIntersect(nextAABB, intersectAABB)) {
                        overlapNext = true;
                    }
                }
            });

            if (overlapLower && !overlapNext) {
                aabbsToCombineWith['index'] = idx;
                aabbsToCombineWith['area'] = areaOf(aabb);
                aabbsToCombineWith['upOrDown'] = -1;
            }
            else if (!overlapLower && overlapNext) {
                aabbsToCombineWith['index'] = idx;
                aabbsToCombineWith['area'] = areaOf(aabb);
                aabbsToCombineWith['upOrDown'] = 1;
            }
            else if (!overlapLower && !overlapNext) {
                aabbsToCombineWith['index'] = idx;
                aabbsToCombineWith['area'] = areaOf(aabb);
                aabbsToCombineWith['upOrDown'] = 0;
            }
        }
    });

    if (aabbToCombineWith['index'] != -1) {
        var combinedAABB = combine(combinedAABBsInSortedOrder[aabbToCombineWith['index']], nextAABB);
        if (aabbToCombineWith['upOrDown'] == -1) {
            combinedAABBsInSortedOrder[aabbToCombineWith['index']] = combinedAABB;
        }
        else {
            combinedAABBsInSortedOrder.push(combinedAABB);
            combinedAABBsInSortedOrder.splice(aabbToConbineWith['index'], 1);
        }
    }
    else {
        combinedAABBsInSortedOrder.push(nextAABB);
    }

    return combinedAABBsInSortedOrder;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this is an optimization, you are likely not interested in an algorithm with a large computational requirement, even if the results are optimal. You'll have to balance running time with good results.

**Without Z-order**

For simplicity, first consider the problem without z-order. A straightforward and effective solution is to greedily consider and combine the rectangles two at a time. The cleverness is in considering both combined boxes and uncombined ones in a efficient way that ensures there is no area-saving pairwise combination left at the end.

```
function minBoxes(boxes) {
    var result = [];

    boxes.forEach(function(box1) {
        var bestCombinedBox,
            bestIndex;
        result.reduce(function(bestSavings, box2, i) {
            var x = Math.min(box1.x, box2.x),
                y = Math.min(box1.y, box2.y),
                w = Math.max(box1.x + box1.w, box2.x + box2.w) - x,
                h = Math.max(box1.y + box1.h, box2.y + box2.h) - y;
            var savings = box1.w * box1.h + box2.w * box2.h - w * h;
            if(savings > bestSavings) {
                bestCombinedBox = {x:x, y:y, w:w, h:h};
                bestIndex = i;
                return savings;
            }
            return bestSavings;
        }, 0);
        if(bestCombinedBox) {
            result[bestIndex] = bestCombinedBox; //faster than splicing
        } else {
            result.push(box1);
        }
    });

    return result;
}

minBoxes([{x:0, y:0, w:5, h:5}, {x:1, y:1, w:5, y:5}]);
```

This runs in `O(N*N)`, when `N` is the number of boxes.

Of course, even this simpler problem has very tricky cases. Consider the following four rectangles.

[image]

It is never advantageous to combine any two of these rectangles. It is best to combine all four, but if you examine them pairwise, you will never combine anything.

That said, this relatively fast algorithm works remarkably well in most cases ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GdLKL/)), so we'll keep it.

**With Z-order**

If rectangles have z-order, then during our calculations, combined rectangles can be considered to have a range of z-orders. I'll add `minZ` and `maxZ` properties for each rectangle to reflect this fact. I'll also add an set (actually, an object whose keys are the value of the set), `overlapping`, of all rectangles that a rectangle overlaps.

I will use `minZ`, `maxZ`, and `overlapping` to ensure that any rectangles I combine do not have a third rectangle that they *both overlap* whose *z-order would come between them*. I also sort the rectangles first by z-order, which may work better when there are many overlapping rectangles. (I am a bit unsure about that, but it can't hurt.)

This runs in `O(N*N*K)` time, where `N` is the number of boxes, and `K` is number of boxes each box overlaps.

NOTE: Below I assume that z-orders are unique. If they are not, it is not hard to make them so.

```
function minBoxes(boxes) {
    boxes = boxes.sort(function(box1, box2) {
        return box1.z - box2.z;
    }).map(function(box1) {
        var overlapping = {};
        boxes.forEach(function(box2) {
            if(box1 != box2
                && box1.x + box1.w > box2.x
                && box2.x + box2.w > box1.x
                && box1.y + box1.h > box2.y
                && box2.y + box2.h > box1.y
            ) {
                overlapping[box2.z] = true;
            }
        });
        return {
            x: box1.x,
            y: box1.y,
            w: box1.w,
            h: box1.h,
            minZ: box1.z,
            maxZ: box1.z,
            overlapping: overlapping
        };
    });

    var result = [];

    boxes.forEach(function(box1) {
        var bestBox,
            bestIndex;

        function combinedBox(box2) {
            var x = Math.min(box1.x, box2.x),
                y = Math.min(box1.y, box2.y);
            return {
                x: x,
                y: y,
                w: Math.max(box1.x + box1.w, box2.x + box2.w) - x,
                h: Math.max(box1.y + box1.h, box2.y + box2.h) - y
            };
        }
        result.reduce(function(bestSavings, box2, i) {
            //check z-order
            var min = Math.max(Math.min(box1.minZ, box2.maxZ), Math.min(box1.maxZ, box2.minZ)),
                max = Math.min(Math.max(box1.minZ, box2.maxZ), Math.max(box1.maxZ, box2.minZ));
            for(var z in box1.overlapping) {
                if(min < z && z < max && z in box2.overlapping) {
                    return bestSavings;
                }
            }
            for(var z in box2.overlapping) {
                if(min < z && z < max && z in box1.overlapping) {
                    return bestSavings;
                }
            }
            //check area savings
            var combined = combinedBox(box2);
            var savings = box1.w * box1.h + box2.w * box2.h - combined.w * combined.h;
            if(savings > bestSavings) {
                bestBox = box2;
                bestIndex = i;
                return savings;
            }
            return bestSavings;
        }, 0);
        if(bestBox) {
            var combined = combinedBox(bestBox);
            combined.minZ = Math.min(box1.minZ, bestBox.minZ);
            combined.maxZ = Math.max(box1.maxZ, bestBox.maxZ);
            combined.overlapping = box1.overlapping;
            for(var z in bestBox.overlapping) {
                combined.overlapping[z] = true;
            }
            result[bestIndex] = combined; //faster than splicing
        } else {
            result.push(box1);
        }
    });

    return result.map(function(box) {
        return {
            x: box.x,
            y: box.y,
            w: box.w,
            h: box.h,
            z: (box.minZ + box.maxZ) / 2 //really, any value in this range will work
        };
    });
}

minBoxes([{x:0, y:0, w:5, h:5, z:0}, {x:1, y:1, w:5, y:5, z:1}]);
```

- [The OP's example](http://jsfiddle.net/9ufp4/)
- The OP's example, but [with rearranged z-orders](http://jsfiddle.net/67UtK/) (so that combining is desired)
- [Random inputs](http://jsfiddle.net/5F2DE/)

There are simpler ways to do this, like sorting by z-order beforehand and hoping for the best, or not allowing two rectangles to be combining if an overlapping rectangle of (only) one of them comes between the two. But those approaches cover fewer cases.

Answer (score 0):

You have an interesting question !

**Something to consider...**

Since canvas is already optimized for drawing speed, **my guess is that simply drawing all rects in z-order will be your fastest solution**.  This way most of the drawing is off-loaded from the CPU to the GPU and your 2 processors are both doing what they do best.

Anyway, back to your question.

**A first pass optimization...**

At it's core, you question starts out to be a question about collision theory: Which of my rectangles intersect each other (which are colliding)?

So your first pass would be to organize your rects into "piles" that minimally intersect each other.

If you draw each of these discrete "piles" onto separate canvases, you will have efficiently separated your rects into manageable canvases.

Current game theory has come up with some very good collision algorithms.  One is called Quadtree and it has a complexity approaching O(n log(n)). Here's a link to Quadtree:

http://gamedev.tutsplus.com/tutorials/implementation/quick-tip-use-quadtrees-to-detect-likely-collisions-in-2d-space/

**After the first pass...**

Quadtree does spacial sorting--very well.  When Quadtree is done, you have non-intersecting piles of rects.

Ok, I lied.  The results are *mostly* nonintersecting.  This is where you might consider the trade-offs between perfection and practicality.  Perfection will cost you some computing power.  Practicality gives up perfection but also costs less computing power.

**"I accept practicality..."**

The Quadtree piles are a good starting point.  If you accept some imperfections the fast & low-cost
path is to simply sort each pile into z-order and draw each pile on a separate canvas.  Then you have a "pretty good" solution. Downside: This practical approach can allow some rects that span 2 piles to be mis-layered on 1 of the 2 piles.  If your design can live with that, you're golden.

**"I want perfection..."**

The Quadtree piles are a good starting point.

Now, sort each pile into z-order and you’ve dealt with 90+% of all your rects.

Any rect that *doesn’t extend* into a neighboring pile is complete and properly ordered.

That’s 90+% of your rects done through the power of Quadtree plus Sorts !.

What remains is the 10% “trespassing” rects that *do extend*  partly in 1 pile and partly in another pile.

How to you properly interleaf those trespassing rects into both neighboring rects?

There’s a neat trick here!.

Background on Quadtree: If you draw each Quadtree pile of rects using a separate canvas, the combined set of canvas piles fills the original canvas completely and without overlap.

Think of the pile canvases as jigsaw pieces that completely build the full picture—no overlap.

So the trick is to draw any trespassing rect in both pile canvases!

Why? Rects that extend beyond the boundary of the canvas are automatically clipped off (canvas won’t display beyond its borders).  *This is exactly what we want!*

The result is that canvas#1 will draw half the trespassing rect properly and neighboring canvas#2 will properly fill in the other half.

Result: Perfection without additional math beyond the Quadtree algorithm plus Sorts!

And keep in mind that Quadtree is designed to handle real-time collisions so it is fast and efficient.

**[Update based on addional comment from questioner]**

I see...so memory is purely the key.

Then, if your design permits you shouldn’t use html canvas at all and instead use an image—or multiple images.

The memory footprint of canvas is always about 4.5 times the size of a static image (ouch!).

Plus images can be quickly blitted by the GPU so memory is cleared/recovered much faster with images.

If your design requires the rects to be dynamic, you would use much less memory by just creating multiple images and transforming them with CSS.  Plus, a side benefit would be much less calculations on the CPU.

Even better, if your rects are all "different colored boxes with a border", you would get a huge memory savings by having each rect be a div element (with background color and a border).  Then do transforms with CSS on the divs.  Huge savings!

Still, your original question remains an interesting exercise ;)

Comment: FYI, rendering performance is not the goal, but memory usage (specifically, GPU memory optimization on Chrome on Android).

Comment: I see...memory is the key.  I've updated my answer with some more thoughts.  Cheers and good luck on your project :)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you consider calculating the [convex hull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull) for the coordinates representing the corners of your shapes. An easy way to calculate it is using a [Graham scan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graham_scan). What you get is the tightest polygon that encloses all corners of your shapes where the corners are either on the polygon or within the same.

Given this polygon, you can easily calculate the minimum width and height of your canvas as

`height = max(y coordinates) - min(y coordinates)
width  = max(x coordinates) - min(x coordinates)`

Z-order doesn't matter to the convex hull calculation.

Comment: How does this handle `non-overlapping objects should be rendered on a separate canvas`?

Comment: If you create all possible groups of your bounding boxes and calculate the area each cover you can find which grouping of your bounding boxes produce the minimal total area. Each group would end up on a separate canvas.

Comment: A grim prospect considering the number of such groups growing exponentially with the number of boxes.

Comment: Sure, if you work on all possible groups but you could discard most of the groups early given you keep track of the best grouping so far and which area that grouping produced.